# I can't put a large list into dictionary plus tuples in Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reduce

Here is the problem. I am creating a list of all combinations of abc...789 as you will see. I want create a dictionary of that list and then send it to a map function.

```
def enumerate(length, possibles):
   ret = []
   if length == 1:
     return list(possibles) 
   else:
     subs = enumerate(length -1, possibles)
     ret = ret + subs
     for ch in possibles:
       for sub in subs:
         ret.append(str(ch) + str(sub))
return ret



datasource = dict(enumerate(4,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"))
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "ex_passcrack.py", line 27, in <module>
   datasource = dict(enumerate(4,"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I don't know what this means. Any help is appreciated.

I have to add to this question. Can anyone tell me how to build a dictionary that is like 
      {0: 'a', 'foo', 1: 'b', 'foo', 2: 'aa', 'foo', 3: 'ab', 'foo', 4: 'ba', 'foo', 5: 'bb', 'foo'}

I apologize if that is wrong in the way it looks (because I don't know). I need each key to have two values.

My current code is:

```
 def combos(length, possibles):
   ret = []
   if length == 1:
     return list(possibles) 
   else:
     subs = combos(length -1, possibles)
     ret = ret + subs
     for ch in possibles:
       for sub in subs:
         ret.append(str(ch) + str(sub))
   return ret

list = combos(2,"ab")
datasource = dict(enumerate(list))
```

And I need the dictionary to be like:

```
{0: 'a', 'foo', 1: 'b', 'foo', 2: 'aa', 'foo', 3: 'ab', 'foo', 4: 'ba', 'foo', 5: 'bb', 'foo'}
```

I am creating all these combinations to send to a map function which hashes the combinations (I truncate down to first five places for ease of comparing). I want to compare the resulting (5 digit) hash within the mapfunction with the argument I pass on the command line (which is a hash itself).

Comment: don't use `enumerate` as a function name since it is the name of a built-in python function

Comment: You are returning a single element, what are the keys and values supposed to be?

Comment: to make a dictionary, you need a list of key-value pairs, you just have values

Comment: You say "I want create a dictionary of that list" but never explain what keys and values you desire to have in that dictionary!  You can only call `dict(somelist)` if each item of `somelist` has exactly two sub-items (e.g, a somelist is a list of lists each of length exactly two), which means to use each "first sub-item" as key and second sub-item as corresponding value.  But the list produced by your dubiously named `enumerate` function is absolutely nothing like that, whence the error you get!

Comment: I don't see error says anything about large list. I think what you need is itertools.permutations look it up.

Comment: Here is an example, `dict([('a', 3), ('b', 5)])` returns `{'a': 3, 'b': 5}`. However, `dict([3, 5])` raises the error you see.

Comment: I apologize for the crappy question, first ever. But I got it. I just wanted all of my combinations enumerated. In a dictionary like this...  {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4 ......etc I figured it out. It was dumb to use enumerate for the function name. Thank you for the comments, they made a light bulb go off. I just renamed the function, put the resulting list in another list, enumerated that list and put into a dictionary.

Comment: @princess_slayer no harm done :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

def myenumerate(length, possibles):
    for i in xrange(length):
        for r in product(possibles, repeat=i + 1):
            yield "".join(r)

print {
    i: [v, 'foo']
    for i, v in enumerate(myenumerate(2, "ab"))
}
```

Result:

```
{0: ['a', 'foo'], 1: ['b', 'foo'], 2: ['aa', 'foo'], 3: ['ab', 'foo'], 4: ['ba', 'foo'], 5: ['bb', 'foo']}
```